# Centos: resume remote task on local console

Tags: linux, centos, terminal, remote

Is is possible to pause a task in a remote session and resume it on server console?
For e.g by pressing Ctrl+Z in remote session windows(inside putty) and run `fg 1` in server console/dekstop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are hoping for, you should be able to do this using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

The big picture of screen is that it creates a virtual terminal which you can attach and detach to other terminals. Assuming that you have screen installed (package name is just `screen` in CentOS I believe) here's one way you could use it:

1. Remote to your machine using Putty or another SSH client.
2. Start `screen`. This creates a virtual terminal that should look basically the same as what you were already looking at.
3. Start your task.
4. You can background it using Ctrl+Z if you'd like, but this isn't necessary. Applications will keep running even once you detach.
5. Detach your current terminal using `Ctrl+a d`. It may feel like you just killed something, but you did not.
6. Just to see how this works, go ahead and run `screen -r`. This will reattach your session and put you back where you were before you detached. Now use `Ctrl+a d` again to detach.
7. That's nice, but the thing that you are interested in is connecting from a separate terminal session. This works exactly the same. Hop off of your SSH connection and run `screen -r` from your local terminal. This should reattach your screen session, and your task should still be running.

Note that this only helps you if you run your application in screen to begin with. I haven't described how to do this with a process that is already running outside of screen.

You can do the exact same thing using [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/), but I described how to do it with screen simply because it's older and more common.